# Android use ksoap2 to connect wcf webservice sometimes fail connect to server

Tags: android, web-services, wcf-data-services, android-ksoap2

I had a problem that when I use ksoap2 to connect wcf webservice, Sometimes that ok I had connect and get data successfully, but sometimes that fail (socketexception: fail to connect to server) internet is ok for all case.

I had set timeout for each connection is 10000ms

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,10000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle such errors gracefully. Remember internet on a mobile device can be unstable. It depends on signal.

For example the cell phone might be moving from a GPRS signal to a 3G signal. This means it effectively restarts the internet connection.

I would do the following:

```
 try
 {
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,10000);
 }
 except(Exception e)
 {
    //Do something with the exception
    // You can try to reconnect.
    // You can report the error to the user.
    // You can do some network diagnostics here.
    // The thing is that networks on mobiles are unreliable so handle the exception.
 }
```